# Quick integer logarithm for special case

Tags: c, optimization, integer, bit-manipulation, logarithm

I have integer values ranging from 32-8191 which I want to map to a roughly logarithmic scale. If I were using base 2, I could just count the leading zero bits and map them into 8 slots, but this is too course-grained; I need 32 slots (and more would be better, but I need them to map to bits in a 32-bit value), which comes out to a base of roughly 1.18-1.20 for the logarithm. Anyone have some tricks for computing this value, or a reasonable approximation, very fast?

My intuition is to break the range down into 2 or 3 subranges with conditionals, and use a small lookup table for each, but I wonder if there's some trick I could do with count-leading-zeros then refining the result, especially since the results don't have to be exact but just roughly logarithmic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the next two bits other than the leading bit. You can first partition the number into the 8 bin, and the next two bits to further divide each bin into four. In this case, you can use a simple shift operation which is very fast.

**Edit**: If you think using the logarithm is a viable solution. Here is the general algorithm:

Let `a` be the base of the logarithm, and the range is `(b_min, b_max) = (32,8191)`. You can find the base using the formula:

```
log(b_max/b_min) / log(a) = 32 bin
```

which give you `a~1.1892026`. If you use this a as the base of the logarithm, you can map the range `(b_min, b_max)` into `(log_a(b_min), log_a(b_max)) = (20.0004,52.0004)`.

Now you only need to subtract the all element by a `20.0004` to get the range `(0,32)`. It guarantees all elements are logarithmically uniform. Done

*Note*: Either a element may fall out of range because of numerical error. You should calculate it yourself for the exact value.

*Note2*: log_a(b) = log(b)/log(a)

Comment: I've seen something that done before (dlmalloc comes to mind), but I don't know if I like how far it deviates from logarithmic. Maybe it's not that bad though.

Answer (score 2):

Table lookup is one option, that table isn't that big.  If an 8K table is too big, and you have a count leading zeros instruction, you can use a table lookup on the top few bits.

```
nbits = 32 - count_leading_zeros(v)  # number of bits in number
highbits = v >> (nbits - 4)          # top 4 bits.  Top bit is always a 1.
log_base_2 = nbits + table[highbits & 0x7]
```

The table you populate with some approximation of log_2

```
table[i] = approx(log_2(1 + i/8.0))
```

If you want to stay in integer arithmetic, multiply the last line by a convenient factor.

Comment: 8k table is way too big, but a table with 8-32 entries wouldn't be bad. I like the simplicity of hwlau's solution though.

Comment: I think our solutions are effectively identical (mine uses the next 3 bits, but that's configurable).

Answer (score 2):

Answer I just came up with based in IEEE 754 floating point:

```
((union { float v; uint32_t r; }){ x }.r >> 21 & 127) - 16
```

It maps 32-8192 onto 0-31 roughly logarithmically (same as hwlau's answer).

Improved version (cut out useless bitwise and):

```
((union { float v; uint32_t r; }){ x }.r >> 21) - 528
```

Comment: How do you rescale to other number of bin?